# Classlist validation for unique selected item

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm trying to create a chat application like messenger.
When I press the button, a new conversation should be started. I want to add a list item in my overview bar on the left but there can only be one selected, and that one has the 'history-item-selected' classname. So every new convo gets that classname, while the others ones get another classname to change it's appearance but it won't work.

```js
const newConvoButton = document.getElementById("newmessage");
const addNewConvo = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const myMessages = document.getElementById('history');

  let newListItem = document.createElement('li');

  newListItem.textContent = "user " + Math.floor(Math.random(2 - 100) * 100);
  myMessages.appendChild(newListItem);

  if (newListItem.classList = 'history-item-selected') {
    newListItem.classList.add('history-item-selected');
  } else {
    newListItem.classList.add('history-item')
  };
};
newConvoButton.addEventListener('click', addNewConvo);
```

```html
<main>
  <div id="top">
    <span>
        <h2>My conversations</h2>
      </span>
    <button type="submit" id="newmessage">+</button>
  </div>

  <div id="messagecontainer">
    <ul id="history"></ul>

    <id id="chatscreen">
      <ul id="messages">
        <li>yolo</li>
      </ul>
      <div id="messagebottom">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Start met typen" size="28" height="auto"> <button type="submit">Send</button>
      </div>
    </id>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a "tautological" way to do what you are trying to do.

```
var addNewConvo = (e)=> {
  var nodes = document.querySelectorAll(".history-item-selected");
  nodes.forEach(function(elem) {
    this.classList.remove("history-item-selected");
  });
  e.target.classList.add("history-item-selected");
}
```

In your CSS, you should have something like

```
.history-item {
  /*Styles for history-item*/
}

.history-item.history-item-selected {
  /*Styles for elements with both */
}
```

Comment: I see what your logic is but it won't work.. Every item I add doesn't get any class

Comment: then tailor the nodes to the ones that do get the class

Comment: What do you mean with "tailor the nodes"?